# Clear Facebook Web Context on Server-side

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I've implemented client-side authentication using the Facebook Javascript SDK.  I check the FacebookWeb context in the Application_AuthenticateRequest event in order to establish if the user is logged in and set the HttpCoontext.Current.User IPrincipal accordingly.

If I delete a user from the database I would like to delete the Facebook web context to ensure that HttpContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated is false. Also if a user de-authorizes my app I would like to delete the facebook web context.  I don't want to log them out of facebook - just delete the facebook web context so the session isn't Authenticated any more.

How do I do this on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

The best method I have found is to manually delete the cookie fbsr_{your app id}.  Of course this can only be done when the user is interacting with your app.  If they delete your app or otherwise deauthorize it while on facebook.com, you won't be able to delete that cookie until they next visit your app.

Here is some code I use to do this with the Facebook C# SDK:

```
string cookieName = "fbsr_" + FacebookApplication.Current.AppId;
if (Request.Cookies[cookieName] != null) {
   HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
   myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
   Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

I do this whenever I get an OAuth exception back from Facebook indicating that the user access token being used is invalid.  Then I force the user to re-authenticate.

Comment: I tried this method - but it looks like the fbsr cookie is re-created every time FB.init is called.  Even if I manually delete the cookie in Firebug and hit refresh it comes back!